# VBA- Run time error 9 Subscript out of range!- A weird case

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to the whole VBA scene. I wrote a macro to sort out a table of info into different tabs. From these new tabs, I am wanting to count the number of rows but I found that macro comes up with the error with the macro generated tabs but it works from ones that I manually opened for testing.

Iam trying to get the Sub test() to work but the Sub Parse_data() part is what is generated the new sorted tabs.

```
  ' Setting variables
Sub parse_data()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer

vcol = 6


Set ws = Sheets("Raw Data")

lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row

title = "A1:K1"
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"


For i = 2 To lr
    On Error Resume Next
    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
        Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If
    ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate

End Sub

Sub test()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw data")

Dim k As Long

k = sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
If k = 1048576 Then
    k = 1
End If
Sheets("Stats").Range("A2") = k
End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` used the way that you are doing so (turned on and never turned off, with no attempts to check for and handle errors) is an awful idea. It could be called "On Error Hide Bug". In any event -- what line triggers the error? We shouldn't have to guess. Please see this: [mcve].

Comment: Oh sorry! Forgot to put that there is no line highlighted...

Comment: "I found that macro comes up with the error" - please describe the error.

Comment: Oh sorry again ahah... It comes up with run time error 9: Subscript out of range.

Comment: Okay. I got rid of it now it comes up with Run time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: What line is highlighted? Some line should be.

Comment: Which Sub are you running? `Test` or `Parse_data` - they don't appear to call each other so you should be able to remove one from your question.

Comment: Oh the bottom one but it uses the new tabs that the first Sub creates so i thought i should include it.

Comment: There is no highlighted line.

Comment: Why not step through the code with the debugger? See this for a quick tutorial if you haven't used it yet: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html

Comment: @ZoeChu Did you exit the message box with the error by hitting `Debug`?

Comment: I haven't looked very much at the question, and this won't be causing the error you describe, but `If k = 1048576 Then` is pointless because Excel only handles a maximum of 1048576 rows in a workbook, so a range starting at row 2 will never contain more than 1048575 rows.

Comment: lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row will return your first line of data, not the end row. Go past that and look up: lr = ws.Cells(1000000, vcol).end(xlUp).Row

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I didn't get a Debug button.

Comment: @JohnColeman I just tried it now. And it stops after the line with the 'on error resume next'. Any tips on how to replace this?

Comment: @YowE3k I did it so it will get all the info from the table as my table ranges in size.

Comment: @Absinthe Sorry, I don't really understand. look up what?

Comment: @ZoeChu - End(xlUp) means you'll go from the selected row (in this case the last row) and search up until you find the next populated row next to an empty row. Obviously you don't want to do that to get the last used row. So go beyond the last row instead, a million rows shoudl do it: lr = ws.Cells(1000000, vcol).end(xlUp).Row. This will give you a true last row.

Comment: @ZoeChu You missed the point of my comment.  I understand why you might be calculating `k`, but `k` will **never** equal `1048576` because the largest row that Excel can handle is row 1048576, and the number of rows in that largest range (range `A2:A1048576`) is only 1048575 so `k` will always be less than or equal to `1048575`.  So `k = 1048576` will **ALWAYS** (until Excel changes the maximum row number) evaluate to `False`.

Comment: @ZoeChu When I get a message box indicating the error, there are usually four buttons at the bottom.  The button labels are `Continue`, `End`, `Debug`, `Help`.    What does your message box look like?  Are you using Excel for Mac?